# AlarmManager Not working Android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

```
String time="00:12:00"
String subs[]=time.split(":");
int hour = Integer.parseInt(subs[0].trim());
int min = Integer.parseInt(subs[1].trim());
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ServiceTest.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(LoginActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

This is my code but it is not working. How can i resolve this?
I just need to call service at a particular moment of time. I am finding trouble in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to this link - http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(LoginActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

please modify like that,not 0!.There is not 0!
Just :`FLAG_ONE_SHOT = 1<<30
       FLAG_NO_CREATE = 1<<29
       FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT = 1<<28
       FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT= 1<<27`

Comment: Appreciate your answer @lollipop but still the bug is same. Code works when I pass inputs manually in digits but I have time in string format. So how can I resolve it? More specific solution can you provide?